# Using online GIS map with shapefiles as basemap in ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.0, basemap

An official website is providing some GIS data as cadastre map with the following addres:

http://cadastre.mimt.gov.ir/Map/Map.aspx?PNid=0

The mentioned website's data are secure and are not available to download for users. I want to display the content of this website in ArcMap background as a basemap to compare with my own data. Because of the wide area of study area it is not possible for me to take screenshots and georef them!
Do you have any suggestion for me to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 2):

This is TMS data. For example one of the layer of your source has such URL:

```
http://map.mimt.gov.ir:8006/maptile.ashx?x=41&y=25&z=6&Key=Pahneh&r=19d775e599cb90aa33108d674cf56701
```

You can add layers as [QMS](https://qms.nextgis.com/) sources and use [ArcQMS plugin](https://my.nextgis.com/downloads/software/arcqms/ArcQMSInstaller.msi) in ArcGIS or [QuickMapServices plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/quick_map_services/) in QGIS.

NOTE: just replace x=41 with x={x}, y=25 with y={y} and z=6 with z={z} while registering this layer.

See additional information here: https://qms.nextgis.com/about

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But I have problems to create a service! Were you able to create one layer of that map as a service?

Comment: There is some kind of protection on this service - each zoom level are protected with **r=** key. For example `http://map.mimt.gov.ir:8006/maptile.ashx?x=41&y=25&z=6&Key=Pahneh&r=19d775e599cb90aa33108d674cf56701` works fine only on zoom level 6 in my QGIS. Needed some kind of proxy which will add **r=** key to url on the fly according the logic of original site. And this proxy can be added to QMS as a TMS service.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you should ask the data custodians whether they can provide an OGC Web Map Service (WMS).  They may say this on that site but it looks like the language is Persian and inaccessible to me.

If they do then you can add a WMS to ArcMap.

Comment: I think that all of data that are available on this website are in restricted area and are not accessible for all users just they can view them in browser style.
It is not possible to ask them for WMS services.